# 500 internal server error while posting data to database with laravel 5 and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hi guys? am trying to post data to the database using laravel 5 and ajax..am also applying using csrf protection by adding

`<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>`

to my layout header and adding the following code to my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});
</script>
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="{{action('QuizController@postQuiz')}}" method="POST">
<div id="name-group" class="form-group">
<label for="name">Please type your question here</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="question">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
</form>
```

This is my JS code:

```
var formData = {
'question'    : $('input[name=question]').val(),
};
// process the form
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'quiz',
data : formData, 
dataType : 'json', 
encode : true
})
// using the done promise callback
.done(function(data) {

// log data to the console to see
console.log(data); 


// ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
$('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

// stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
event.preventDefault();
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('create/quiz', array(
'as' => 'post-quiz',
'uses' => 'QuizController@postQuiz'
));
```

When my controller is like the following:

```
public function postQuiz()
{
if(Request::ajax()) {
$question = Request::get('question');
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = $question;
echo json_encode($data);
   }
```

the ajax call works and it returns,

`Object {success: true, message: "test question"}`

but when I try posting data to the database using:

```
public function postQuiz()
{
if(Request::ajax()) {
$question = Request::get('question');
DB::table('questions')->insert([
'question' => $question,
]);
     }
```

I get the following from the console

```
POST http://localhost/leoschool-laravel5/public/create/quiz 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"success":true,"message":"test question"}<!DOCTYPE htm…l>↵</div>↵↵            </div>↵    </body>↵</html>", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks..﻿

Comment: look at the server error log for details about the 500.

Comment: No wonder if it will throw 500 error. `'question' => $question,` _,_ is  used when array has 1 item. Remove , from Array.

Comment: @Rajlaksh: commas after last element in the array are allowed in PHP

Comment: have you check storage/log/laravel log? there will be fatal error or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start is with Chrome Developer tools.  Load your page with the tools open and fire the event that does the AJAX request.

Under the network tab of the tools, it will show you every request made and allow you to preview the response as if you were not using AJAX.  This will show you the laravel stack trace.  I think the problem is that you're using facades and they're not namespaced correctly.

Change your controller function to this and see if it works:

```
public function postQuiz()
{
    if(\Request::ajax()) {
        $question = \Request::get('question');
        \DB::table('questions')->insert([
            'question' => $question,
        ]);
}
```

With the above instruction on how to use dev tools and with the corrected code, you should be able to fix your problem.  A better way to write this code would look like this though:

```
// assuming you have these models setup
// this uses dependency injection
public function postQuiz(Request $request, Question $question)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $newQuestion = $request->get('question');
        //add fields here to create new question with
        $question->create([ /*stuff*/ ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kyle..Stupid mistake but you are right, I hadn't namespaced the laravel facade DB. Thank you so much :-)